# Set cookie - jquery modal Confirm dialogue

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, setcookie

This jquery_modal_confirm_dialogue is working after many experiments.
When our visitors agree to our Terms of Use, they are redirected to the product page **products.html**

I desperately need to set a cookie.
 - if they do not agree, when they attempt to visit products.html, this
   is not visible and displays the modal dialogue again

Could you please give me a hint?
(jquery 1.3.2.min.js)

**This is my jqmodal.js**

```
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes')
          (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}


$().ready(function() {
  $('#confirm').jqm({overlay: 88, modal: true, trigger: false});

  // trigger a confirm whenever links of class alert are pressed.
  $('a.confirm').click(function() { 
    confirm('About to visit: '+this.href+' !',this.href); 
    return false;
  });
});// JavaScript Document
```

**This is my index.html:**

```
 <a href="http://products.html/" class="confirm">Products</a> 

    <div class="jqmConfirm" id="confirm">

    <div id="ex3b" class="jqmConfirmWindow">
        <div class="jqmConfirmTitle clearfix">
            <h1>Terms of Use</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="jqmConfirmContent">
        <p class="jqmConfirmMsg"></p>
            <p>Important legal information</p></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Decline" />
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, finally! I was missing the callback when the cookie exists and these tics '' around the value of the cookie. Here is how it looks like. Please, let me know if there is some obvious mistake. (many thanks for your support)

```
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'Proceed'){
           $.cookie("agreed_to_terms", '1', { expires : 1, path: '/' }); //set cookie, expires in 365 days
           (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        }
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}


$().ready(function() {
  $('#confirm').jqm({overlay: 88, modal: 'true', trigger: false});

  // trigger a confirm whenever links of class alert are pressed.
  $('a.confirm').click(function() { 
    if ($.cookie('agreed_to_terms') == '1'){window.location.href = callback =
            callback()
       //they already have cookie set
    }else{
       confirm('About to visit: '+this.href+' !',this.href); 
    }
    return false;
  });
});// JavaScript Document
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want them to accept the confirmation, and have it set a cookie. Then the next time they show up not dislay the legal thing.

First, get this jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

It allows you to do things like:

```
$.cookie("test", 1);
```

So you would modify your code like so:

```
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes'){
           $.cookie("didAccept", 1, { expires : 365 }); //set cookie, expires in 365 days
           (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        }
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}


$().ready(function() {
  $('#confirm').jqm({overlay: 88, modal: true, trigger: false});

  // trigger a confirm whenever links of class alert are pressed.
  $('a.confirm').click(function() { 
    if ($.cookie('the_cookie') == 1){
       //they already have cookie set
    }else{
       confirm('About to visit: '+this.href+' !',this.href); 
    }
    return false;
  });
});// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: Hi Paul! 
Many thanks for your quick response.

I believe I am doing it correctly, but the modal_dialogue is not displaying anymore.
(maybe the cookie works very well, either I broke it all) :D

I have ovewritten my tou.js with your code.

Do I need to include any other piece of code along my html?
Is it possible that my jquery version does not suit?

How could I check whether the cookie works?

(thanks for your patience, this is my 3rd week on these matters)

Comment: Good question. Could you setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ example of your code and post the link here? that will give me a better idea on the libraries you are using.

Comment: I managed to make it displayed.
just renamed "the_cookie", "didAccept" andvalue "Proceed" instead of "yes".

I learned to check if the cookie gets set.

the only issue now is after setting the cookie i dont get redirected anymore :(

yes, i will load it up (thanks again... this is driving me nuts)